# async function in $onInit not binding to HTML

Tags: angularjs, promise, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

### async function in OnInit firing after template has loaded

Apologies if this has been asked. I couldn't seem to find something speaking to my specific scenario.

In my controller, I define an $onInit function that calls a function that that in turn calls an async function. The async function has a catch block that sets a boolean for an `ng-if` in the template (controls whether an error message should display):

controller:

```
$onInit() {
    initFn();
}

function initFn() {
    innerFn();
}

function innerFn() {
    asyncFn
        .then(() => { 
            // does some stuff 
        })
        .catch(() => { 
            boolVal = true;
        })
}
```

template:

```
<div ng-if="boolVal">some-error-message</div>
```

I test this by sending back a `Promise.reject()` for `asyncFn` but the error message doesn't show. `boolVal`, however, is `true`. What I think is happening is that the template compiles and builds before the async call is able to finish. How do I ensure that all API calls are completed in `$onInit` before the template has loaded? If that isn't the problem, what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Please supply an [mcve]. I recommend using https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I test this by sending back a `Promise.reject()` for `asyncFn`

The ES6 promises returned by `Promise.reject()` are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. Instead, return AngularJS promises:

```
function asyncFn () {
    if (/* error condition */) {
        return $q.reject();
    };
}
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)</sup>

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - `$q.reject](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#reject)

---

> what are common scenarios/services that I should be aware

1. Beware of ES6 promises -- use AngularJS promises
2. Beware of third-party promises -- use `$q.when` to convert to AngularJS promises
3. Beware of `async`/`await` -- they return ES6 promises
4. Beware of `window.setTimeout` - use the [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service
5. Beware of `window.setInterval` -- use the [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service
6. Beware of `jQuery.ajax` -- use the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service

### Event from outside the AngularJS framework

1. Beware of `element.addEventListener`
2. Beware of `jQuery.on`
3. Beware of events from third-party APIs / libraries

You can also use [$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript.

[image]

Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is **needed only when implementing custom event callbacks, or when working with third-party library callbacks.**

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)
- [AngularJS $scope / $rootScope Class API Reference - $apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)